# How can I enable Mobile mode for chromium browser on start

Tags: android, c++, google-chrome-devtools, chromium, chromium-os

I found the attribute: `emulate_mobile_enabled_` in file **third_party\blink\renderer\core\inspector\dev_tools_emulator.cc**
, I have set it to `true` , however after building and starting chrome it still hasn't turned into **mobile ** mode . It seems it's not in this file, where should I fix it?

I also tried changing the `useragent` and `platform` to Android successfully, but after starting Chrome, the mouse and screen are still in Chrome for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

set is true just like you mention headless='new'
isMobile='true'